# Java Eclipse - Placing a space between my JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, space, joptionpane

I'm messing around in Eclipse (beginner) and I have a gui that I made to produce a final output of, "Your name is John Smith Doe". However, when it outputs the final name, it reads like this, "Your name is JohnSmithDoe". There is no spacing between the first, middle, and last name. How can I add the spacing between the names? My code is below.

Thank you,

Don

```
String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
String mn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your middle name");
String ln = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your last name");

String name = fn + mn + ln;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is " + name, "Name", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include space characters in your String: `String name = fn + " " + mn + " " + ln;`